# Proof that $\sum_{i=1}^n{1} = n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, arithmetic, natural-numbers

It seems obvious that $$\forall n \in \Bbb Z^+, \sum_{i=1}^n{1} = n $$

However, I'm having trouble coming up with a formal proof for this.

Given a concrete number like $4$, we can say that $$\sum_{i=1}^4{1} = 1+1+1+1 = 2+1+1=3+1=4$$ by the definitions of summation, 2, 3, and 4. But how can we formally show this for an arbitrary positive integer?

I wonder if we can use the definitions of multiplication and the multiplicative identity, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Just use induction.

Comment: What Workaholic said.

Comment: To repeat what has already been said twice, use induction. To do that, we have to *define* what we mean by $\sum_1^n f(k)$. The usual definition is recursive, that it is $\left(\sum_1^{n-1}f(k)\right)+f(n)$.

Comment: But what about induction? Ypnypn feels correctly that everything is hovering over the emptiness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Use induction.

To get you started, suppose we have the statement
$$
S(n) : \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n
$$
that you are trying to prove. Fix some $k\geq 1$ and assume
$$
S(k) : \sum_{i=1}^k 1 = k
$$
is true. Then we need to show that 
$$
S(k+1) : \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} 1 = k+1
$$
follows. Beginning with the left side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} 1 &= \sum_{i=1}^k 1 + 1\tag{using definition of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
                   &= k + 1\tag{by $S(k)$},
\end{align}
we reach the right side of $S(k+1)$.

The result, then, follows by mathematical induction.

Comment: Don't skip the case $k=1$. Given your name, I'd assume you wouldn't forget that. The above proof without $k=1$ would also show $\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n+1$. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Absolutely--never forget the base case! I just wanted to get the OP started though. I did not want to do the *entire* proof for him. Also, what I provided, as we both know, is simply the mechanics of the main part of the proof. If this were to be turned in, then I would expect a much more fluid composition as I have provided in some other induction proofs. Good point though :)